# switch tab with vimscript?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I want do something like this:

1. check if a split named `__Potion_Bytecode__` exists
2. if exists, switch to the split with name
3. if not, new a split named `__Potion_Bytecode__`

Here is code I am now doing:

```
function! PotionShowBytecode()
    " Here I need to check if split exists
    "  open a new split and set it up
    vsplit __Potion_Bytecode__
    normal! ggdG
endfunction
```

Comment: Switch "tab" or switch "window"?

Comment: @romainl, I think it is a tab, because I new split with `vsplit`

Comment: `:(v)split`  creates new split windows. tabs are created with `:tab`. split windows can be presented simultaneously on a same tab. We can't look at things in two different tabs simultaneously.

Comment: `:sbuffer somename` should work, depending on the value of the `'switchbuf'` option.

Comment: @romainl I just new another split with `:sbuffer somename`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [lh-vim-lib](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-vim-lib), I have [`lh#buffer#jump()`](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-vim-lib/blob/master/autoload/lh/buffer.vim#L84) that does exactly that. It relies on [another function](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-vim-lib/blob/master/autoload/lh/buffer.vim#L84) to find a window where the buffer could be.

```
" Function: lh#buffer#find({filename}) {{{3
" If {filename} is opened in a window, jump to this window, otherwise return -1
function! lh#buffer#find(filename)
  let b = bufwinnr(a:filename) " find the window where the buffer is opened
  if b == -1 | return b | endif
  exe b.'wincmd w' " jump to the window found
  return b
endfunction

function! lh#buffer#jump(filename, cmd)
  let b = lh#buffer#find(a:filename)
  if b != -1 | return b | endif
  call lh#window#create_window_with(a:cmd . ' ' . a:filename)
  return winnr()
endfunction
```

Which uses [another function](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-vim-lib/blob/master/autoload/lh/window.vim#L50) to work around the extremely annoying E36:

```
" Function: lh#window#create_window_with(cmd) {{{3
" Since a few versions, vim throws a lot of E36 errors around:
" everytime we try to split from a windows where its height equals &winheight
" (the minimum height)
function! lh#window#create_window_with(cmd) abort
  try
    exe a:cmd
  catch /E36:/
    " Try again after an increase of the current window height
    resize +1
    exe a:cmd
  endtry
endfunction
```

If you want to work with tabs, you'll have to use tab* functions instead.

Comment: why not replace `call lh#window#create_window_with(a:cmd . ' ' . a:filename)` with `vsplit a:filename_`

Comment: Because of E36 that I get a lot lately. I use many, many split windows when I work. I often end-up with the annoying "E36: not enough space to open a split window" (this is not the exact error message). With this hack, I work around vim limitation and force the split -- if it can be forced.