# How do I detect if a specific buffer exists in Vimscript?

Tags: vim

I want to detect if a specific file is already opened (visible) in a Vim window with Vimscript. If the file isn't open (visible) in a vim-window, I want to open it via `:edit`.

I have a variable with the expanded file path and want to check whether a file with that expanded filepath is already opened (visible) in a Vim window.

How can I do that?

A second question about that is how I can get a list with all opened (visible) files and all not visible but open files (buffers).

I think this is mainly about buffers.

## SOLUTION (2016.02.18)

thx @muru for pointing in to the needed functions.
my test solution looks like that in the moment

```
function! ChooseBuffer(buffername)
    let bnr = bufwinnr(a:buffername)
    if bnr > 0
       :exe bnr . "wincmd w"
    else
       echo a:buffername . ' is not existent'
       silent execute 'split ' . a:buffername
    endif
 endfunction
:nnoremap <leader><leader>d :call ChooseBuffer("divramod.vim")<cr>
:nnoremap <leader><leader>1 :call ChooseBuffer("vim/plugin/divramod/test1.vim")<cr>
:nnoremap <leader><leader>2 :call ChooseBuffer("vim/plugin/divramod/test2.vim")<cr>
:nnoremap <leader><leader>t :call ChooseBuffer("vim/plugin/divramod/test.vim")<cr>
```

It seems to be the case, that bufwinnr() finds "divramod.vim" despite the fact, that the buffername in the bufferlist is called "vim/plugin/divramod/divramod.vim". It seems to use a regex for searching inside the buffername. i have to experiment, what happens when two buffers with the same filename but different file pathes are opened.

Comment: Start with `:help functions`.

Comment: If you're interested in Vimscript, do checkout [vi.se].

Comment: A very similar question was asked yesterday. Not exactly a duplicate, but close. I could give the exact same answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35427862/switch-tab-with-vimscript

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the [`bufwinnr()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#bufwinnr%28%29) function:

```
bufwinnr({expr})                                        bufwinnr()
            The result is a Number, which is the number of the first
            window associated with buffer {expr}.  For the use of {expr},
            see bufname() above.  If buffer {expr} doesn't exist or
            there is no such window, -1 is returned.
```

And from `bufname()`:

```
            If the {expr} argument is a string it must match a buffer name
            exactly.  The name can be:
            - Relative to the current directory.
            - A full path.
            - The name of a buffer with 'buftype' set to "nofile".
            - A URL name.
```

So, something like:

```
if bufwinnr(myfile) > 0
  echo "Already open"
endif
```

Comment: thx, that solved my problem. can you say if there is a function that returns all buffernames in vimscript?

Comment: @divramod not that I know of, but you can do something like `:bufdo expand('%')` for that, I suppose.

Comment: what version of vim are you running? In my :help for bufname(), it says 'If {expr} is a String, it is used as a |file-pattern| to match with the buffer names.', so to get exact matches, I'll have to use bufname("^file$"), because bufname("file") will match "file_but_not_the_one_I_want". This is on 7.4p1707, and I've been looking in the changelogs to see when the change was made, to no avail.

Comment: @aktivb :facepalm: looks like I made a mistake and read the help for `bufexists` instead - the text quoted matches `:h bufexists`.

Comment: @muru ah, that's good to hear, means I don't have to take version into account for what I'm making

Comment: @aktivb nope. Your quote goes back at least to the 7.3 days.

Comment: Problem is, `bufwinnr()` only deals with the current tab page.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to know if a buffer *exists*, not that it both exists and is open in some window, use `bufexists(buffer_number)`. I recommend  using `bufexists(str2nr(buffer_number))`, in case your buffer variable happens to be a string. This will return `1`, even if your buffer exists, but isn't open in any current windows.

Answer (score 3):

`bufwinnr()` doesn't take into account other tab pages. Since Vim [patch 7.4.1558](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/9cdf86b86f5fdb5a45b682f336846f9d9a9c6f1f) there's a new function called `win_findbuf({bufnr})`, which will return a list of all window-IDs that contain buffer, from *all* tab pages.

Comment: It's all right. However, how should implement it in lower version?